# Unbound Local Error python

Tags: python, api, syntax-error, reddit, praw

I need help figuring out why I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prawtest3.py", line 25, in <module>
    commentMatcher()
  File "prawtest3.py", line 13, in commentMatcher
    commentCollection.append(comment)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'commentCollection' referenced before assignment
```

This is my code. For background information, I am trying to create a reddit bot that compares a persons comments and then pms a user when the person they are monitoring submits a new comment. If you see a problem with the functionality as well, feel free to share your input. I just need to diagnose my code first to get rid of the syntactical errors before worrying about the semantic ones.

```
import praw
import time 

r = praw.Reddit('PRAW related-question monitor by u/testpurposes v 1.0.')
r.login()
user = r.get_redditor('krumpqueen')
commentCollection = []
commentComparison = []

def commentMatcher():
    comments = user.get_comments(limit = 4)
    for comment in comments:
        commentCollection.append(comment)
    time.sleep(60)
    comments = user.get_comments(limit = 4)
    for comment in comments:
        commentComparision.append(comment)
    if commentCollection[1] != commentComparision[1]:
        r.send_message('krumpqueen', 'just made a new comment', 'go check now')
        commentCollection = list(commentComparision)
    else:
    r.send_message('krumpqueen', 'did not made a new comment', 'sorry')

while(True):
    commentMatcher()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `commentCollection` makes python (incorrectly<sup>1</sup>) assume that `commentCollection` is a local (since you have an assignment to it later and no `global` statement).  When you try to append to the local (which hasn't been created yet) python throws the UnboundLocalError.

<sup><sup>1</sup>Of course, it's not python making an incorrect assumption, That's how the language is designed to work.</sup>

Comment: That's not what happens; if it were, the error would be raised at the point of the assignment to `commentCollection`, not the attempt to `append` to it.

Comment: @user2357112 -- Thanks, you're quite right.  I've updated (hopefully correcting my error).

Answer (score 1):

You do `commentCollection = list(commentComparision)` inside of `commentMatcher`. Because you've done this, Python concludes you have a local name `commentCollection`.

Your code fails for the same reason that the code

```
def foo():
    bar.append(3)
    bar = []
```

would fail.

To get `commentCollection = list(commentComparision)` to a) rebind the global name `commentCollection`, and b) not make it look like this is a local name at all, add `global commentCollection` as the first line in the definition of `commentMatcher`.

In serious code, you wouldn't want to manage your state as globals like this, but rather you'd make an object.